# Отсортировать структуру по возрастанию

Tags: c#, сортировка, структуры

Не знаю как сортировать структуру по возростанию номера рейса

```
public struct Aeroflot
{
    public string Destination;
    public string Number;
    public string PlaneModel;
}
class Program
{
    static void GetValues(Aeroflot[] Flights)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS; i++)
        {
            Aeroflot flight = new Aeroflot();

            Console.WriteLine("Input destination");
            flight.Destination = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input flight number");
            flight.Number = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input plane model");
            flight.PlaneModel = Console.ReadLine();

            Flights[i] = flight;

        }
    }
    const int NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS = 2;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Aeroflot[] Flights = new Aeroflot[NUMBER_OF_FLIGHTS];

        GetValues(Flights);

        int matches = 0;
              string DestinationToCompare = Console.ReadLine();
              
              for (int i=0; i<Flights.Length; i++)
               {
                      if (Flights[i].Destination == DestinationToCompare)
                      {
                              Console.WriteLine(Flights[i].Number + " " + Flights[i].PlaneModel + " " + Flights[i].Destination);
                              matches++;
                      }
              }
                
              if (matches == 0)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("There is no matches"); 
              }
    } 
}
```

Comment: [Array.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0) позволяет сортировать массив

Comment: вы можете использовать [LINQ](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php), а именно `Flights.OrderBy(aeroflot => aeroflot.Number);`